# path helper for form_for tag with url options generates wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, path, form-for

I am using form_for helper with *url* option like this:

```
<%= form_for  @security_user, url: security_users_manage_securities_path(@security_user),
              html: { class: 'default', method: :put, id: 'security-default-form' } do |f| %>
```

but the

```
security_users_manage_securities_path(@security_user)
```

returns me the following string:

```
/security_users_manage_securities.105
```

when I need the following one:

```
/security_users_manage_securities/105
```

Has anyone un idea why the id of the @security_user parameter is concatenated with '**.**' instead '**/**'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this helper in singular mode, e.g.

```
security_users_manage_security_path(@security_user)
```

This should generate

```
/security_users_manage_securities/105
```

Plural is used when you want to get url to list and then you shouldn't pass any params:

```
security_users_manage_securities_path
```

returns:

```
/security_users_manage_securities
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem already.

It may be possible, you have define your route for 'security_users_manage_security' with collection like

```
collection do 
  post :security_users_manage_securities
end
or 
post :security_users_manage_securities, :on => collection
```

if you hit `rake routes | grep security_users_manage_securities` command on terminal, then you will find route for `security_users_manage_securities` something like this

```
controller_name/method_name(.:format)    controller_name#method_name
```

there is no option to pass any argument in url.

If you have to make url with parameter then define url with member.

If you have to pass parameter in this condition also, then you define your url some like

```
security_users_manage_securities_path(:user_id => @security_user)
```

now url will be generated something like `controller_name/method_name?user_id = XXX`